# Can I re-use my Office license after re-installing Windows?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, license-key

I had Windows 7 Ultimate RC and Office Home and Student 2007 installed.

Then yesterday, I installed Windows 7 Ultimate.

The Office box says it includes "3 Home PC Licenses".

Can I install Office again without using another one of the 3 licenses?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , You can use it

[To add a source:](http://forums.techarena.in/ms-office-support/745341.htm)

> Hey Guys,
>
> Yes, that would be how the licensing
>   would work. If you are "transfering" a
>   license to another machine, you would
>   have to uninstall it from the machine
>   that will not be using the license.
>
> Once you install the Office on the new
>   machine you want to use it, you will
>   have to contact the Microsoft Office
>   Activation line 1- 888-652-2342, the
>   Internet Activation will not allow you
>   to do so.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Max Sinnis Office and Outlook Setup
>   Support

Since uninstalling isn't monitored, you will only have to call IF there is a problem with the activation

Personally, I never had any problems with reinstalling before, but that was the Business edition

Comment: So does Office detect that I'm re-installing on the same computer as before and not use another one of the 3 licenses?

Comment: It should be fine if the hardware is unchanged. If it fails activation you can always re-activate by phone and explain the situation and tell them it is only on three machines.
You have the right to move your three installs around anyway, as long as it is the retail version of H&S edition, not some OEM one (I don't even think there is an OEM of H&S)

Comment: The time I had to reinstall XP SP2 on a laptop, H&S Office wouldn't reregister automatically, so I had to call Microsoft.  No big deal, but I did have to call.

Comment: I added my answer, since it makes no sense to answer the same thing in a new answer